# How do I access an API on my host machine from a Docker container?

Tags: docker, networking, localhost

I have a `docker-compose` that spins up 2 Docker containers.  One is an application (on `port:8090`) and the other is a database (on `port:5432`).  I also have a Windows application that has an API accessible through `localhost:8002`.  I want to use my container that has the application to read data from the `localhost:8002` API, then move that data to my database in my other Docker container.

For `docker-compose`, I mapped `port 5432:5432` and `port 8090:8090` for the database and application containers, respectively.  I have tested my application **non-dockerized** where I call the Windows API and then write it to `port:5432` and it works properly.

However, after Dockerizing my application, `localhost:8002` is now no longer localhost for my Dockerized application and is now unreachable.  I am wondering how I can reach my host `localhost:8002`, hit that API, then move that data to my other container.

Comment: It depends on how you have your networking set up.  By default, you get a bridged network.  If you `ifconfig` in your container, the gateway address should be the locally-known IP address of your host.

Comment: Hi Tim, I assume you mean `ipconfig`.  I have indeed tried this and feel like this is the answer, however, there are so many IPv4 ports I can use.  Which one would I use?  I have: `Ethernet adapter vEthernet`, `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (WSL)`, `VMWare Networks`, `Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi`, `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (nat)`.

Comment: If you do `route print`, there should only be one gateway.  Hopefully.

Comment: That sounds like the problem described in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach); do the answers there help you?  (On a Windows host, try using the special host name `host.docker.internal` to connect back to the host.)

Comment: Hey David, I actually tried that as well with `http://host.docker.internal:8002` and `host.docker.internal:8002`.  For whatever reason, that did not work either and I had no idea why.  Perhaps I am specifying the function incorrectly, I will explore this further.
Also for Tim, when i ran a `route print`, I actually got about 35 routes in the IPv4 Route Table :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 16 hours of blood, sweat, and tears.  Mostly tears, here's the answer for whoever may be using this in the future.

TL;DR expose your local `nat` network to your docker containers in `docker-compose` by:

```
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: nat
```

Note, on Windows, running a `docker network ls` should give something like:

```
NETWORK ID     NAME             DRIVER    SCOPE
6b30a7dcf6e0   Default Switch   ics       local
26305680ad62   WSL              ics       local
b52f5e497eba   nat              nat       local
4a4fd550398f   none             null      local
```

The `docker-compose` is simply connecting the docker network to your host network (required for auto-restart of containers after computer restarts as well, but off-topic).

Afterwards, I had to run an `ipconfig` to find the `IPv4` port that corresponds to my `nat` port.  Here, there can be many `IPv4` IP addresses, find the one that says `Ethernet adapter vEthernet (nat)`.

Then, use the `IPv4 Address` corresponding to the `nat` network for any applications running on your local machine.

For example, my application ran on `localhost:8002`.  Here, I changed my host to `http://172.31.160.1:8002` and it worked.